# How would i make this program start over upon triggering the else statement?

Tags: python

I'm curious how I would make this program automatically prompt the user for another value after triggering the else statement.

```
tires = float(input('How many tires would you like?'))
if tires == 2:
    print('That will be $250')

if tires == 4:
    print('That will be $400')

else:
    print('That is not a valid input, please try again')
```

Comment: Wrap it on a `while` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the entire thing in a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    tires = float(input('How many tires would you like?'))

    if tires == 2:
        print('That will be $250')
        break

    elif tires == 4:
        print('That will be $400')
        break

    else:
        print('That is not a valid input, please try again')
        # keep looping
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! I was wrestling with it for a bit, forgot to capitalize the T in "True," after I added the loop!